# Creating and using derived types in XML schema

Tags: xml, xsd, complextype, derived-types, simpletype

**Edited in order to make a complete schema that can be tested if needed as suggested in the comments below**

Let's say I have a small XML schema defined as follows:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
           targetNamespace="tns:grades"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:tns="tns:grades"
           vc:minVersion="1.1">

    <xs:element name="grades">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="tns:grade" minOccurs="0" maxOcccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="grade">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="xs:double">
                    <xs:attribute name="type" type="tns:gradeType" use="required"/>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:simpleType name="gradeType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="simple|complex"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="simple">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:double">
            <xs:pattern value="1.0|1.3|1.7|2.0|2.3|2.7|3.0|3.3|3.7|4.0|4.7|5.0"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="complex">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:double">
            <xs:minInclusive value="1.0"/>
            <xs:maxInclusive value="5.0"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

</schema>
```

The type *gradeType* is being used to determine how the value of the **grade** element restricted and how it is to be evaluated. What I want to do is use the specified above *simple* and *complex* types as two derivatives of *gradeType*. The *simple* type of grade allows me to use only a limited set of choices due to a restriction in the grading scale. The *complex* type on the other hand allows me basically an unlimited interval between 1.0 and 5.0 since I use it to compute the arithmetic mean of multiple *simple* grades and round it to the closest *simple* grade available in an XSLT. However I have no idea how to change my **gradeType** in such a way so that both simple types *simple* and *complex* can be used when I create a **grade** element. I have read about deriving types (here: *simple*,*complex*) from a base class (here: *gradeType*) but it seems I simply don't get it.

Example how I imagine **grade** should look like:

```
<grades>
    <grade type="simple">1.7</grade>
    <grade type="simple">2.0</grade>
    <grade type="complex">1.4</grade>
    <grade type="simple">5.0</grade>
    <grade type="complex">4.6</grade>
</grades>
```

**Edit**
As suggested below the **xs:union** element was tested:

```
<xs:simpleType name="gradeType">
    <xs:union memberTypes="tns:simple tns:complex"/>
</xs:simpleType>
```

This leads to following two errors in all **grade** elements in my XML document:

> cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.3: 'simple' is not a valid value of union type 'gradeType'.
>
> cvc-attribute.3: The value 'simple' of attribute 'type' on element 'grade' is not valid with respect to its type, 'gradeType'.

**Edit 2:**
As noted by @lexicore I have it more or less all wrong or probably just explained badly. I will try to use pseudo-code to describe how the **grade** element is supposed to work:

```
if gradeType == "simple"
    value of GRADE has to obey the rules defined by the SIMPLE type
else if gradeType == "complex"
    value of GRADE has to obey the rules defined by the COMPLEX type
```

Answer (score 1):

After long hours of struggling I came up with the following and it is doing what I want it to be doing with 2 exceptions:

- the **type** attribute even though with usage set to *required* can actually be omitted, which is a clear violation of the way my **grade** element is supposed to be working
- **grade** can be empty all of a sudden -_-

Those problems come most probably from the fact that my **grade** attributes come actually with my base type **gradeType**.

As you can see below I have reworked my XSD concerning the part handling the **grade** element. I have added some of the additional attributes that I needed (haven't described @term and @attempt in my question). You can see the XSD code below after the explanation that follows.

I started with some brute-force techniques experimenting what sort of combinations I can make with **xs:complexType** and **xs:simpleType** because my idea was actually circling around those two. Then I started looking at **alternatives** of describing the same element in multiple ways. The keyword **alternatives** gave me an idea to look for such an element and indeed **xs:alternative** is the solution in my case. The major breakthrough was when I remembered that an element can have 4 types of content: empty (that is no content at all), text, another element or combined. The main issue was that all the examples I managed to find concerning **xs:alternative** were with alternatives for a nested structure of child elements of the current element that they were part of. I decide to test it with *text* content and it actually worked. So here is how it works: you create a **complexType** **gradeType**, which is used for two things - describes the attributes of my **grade** element and is a base for the two types of grades I want to have - **simple** and **complex**. It is also defined as an extension of the **simpleType** **xs:double**. All three have in common the fact that they are of **complexType** and with **simpleContent** the second being required when you want to use **xs:restriction** and create a container for a **simpleType** (**xs:double**).

```
<xs:element name="grade">
    <xs:alternative test='@type="simple"' type="tns:simple"/>
    <xs:alternative test='@type="complex"' type="tns:complex"/>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="gradeType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:double">
            <xs:attribute name="attempt" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:nonNegativeInteger">
                        <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="2"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="3"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
            <xs:attribute name="term" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:pattern value="(WS|SS)[0-9]{2}"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
            <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="simple">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:restriction base="tns:gradeType">
            <xs:enumeration value="1.0"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="1.3"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="1.7"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="2.0"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="2.3"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="2.7"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="3.0"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="3.3"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="3.7"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="4.0"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="4.7"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="5.0"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="complex">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:restriction base="tns:gradeType">
            <xs:minInclusive value="1.0"/>
            <xs:maxInclusive value="5.0"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

So that's it. The only thing that remains is for me to figure out how to include my attributes in the **grade** element and not in the **gradeType** since this leads (for some unknown for me at least reason) to the problems I described at the beginning of my own answer.

Comment: Cool that you posted it.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you just want the [union datatype](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#union-datatypes)?

```
<xs:simpleType name="gradeType">
    <xs:union memberTypes="tns:simple tns:complex"/>
</xs:simpleType>
```

(Not tested.)

This should allow you to use values of `tns:simple` or `tns:complex` types as `tns:gradeType`.

> The value space and lexical space of a union datatype are the union of the value spaces and lexical spaces of its memberTypes.

See the relevant examples from the [here](http://www.datypic.com/books/defxmlschema1/chapter11.html) (can't copy as not sure about the license).

Also consider using `xs:enumeration` in `tns:simple` instead of `xs:pattern`.

Comment: When applying what you've suggested I get an error in each of my grade-elements: 'simple' (or 'complex' respectively) is not a valid type of union type 'gradeType'. The value 'simple' (or 'complex' respectively) of attribute 'type' on element 'grade' is not valid with respect to its type, 'gradeType'. It should be working though from all the examples I managed to find on the Internet (including the link you've posted) so far and the way I know union works. I wonder what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @rbaleksandar Well, why don't you ask another question and post a minimal reproducing example then? There is a lot of qualified people here to spot the problem.

Comment: I have edited my question to include a full minimalistic XML schema. As for the "why don't you ask another question" I still consider the union-issue as part of this problem described in my initial question.

Comment: @rbaleksandar Please post a sample XML. Right now I think you have a `sample` there somewhere instead of a value like `1.0`.

Comment: I know what you mean now but I have no idea how to adjust my schema. See the example I've added. This is how I imagine it to be. Since XSD does not support if-statements (like in XSLT) I don't know how my 'gradeType' derivatives can control the value of the 'grade' element.

Comment: Ah, ok. This is a completely different story. Not possible with XSD 1.0 but with 1.1. I think Michael Kay once ave an answer on that, I'll take a look.

Comment: @rbaleksandar Found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23545674/xml-validation-different-child-tags-based-on-attribute-value/23564251#23564251
And also see questions posted in the first comment:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24162153/xsd-how-to-specify-element-structure-depending-on-its-attribute-value