# XSD: add restrictions dependent on attribute of parent

Tags: xml, xsd

In mine xml-file I have a lot of settings, dependent of the attribute "type", there are other elements required.
For example the type "toggle" has always the following elements:

```
<setting type="toggle" savename="brightnessToggle" color="orange">
      <label>Verlichting</label>
      <default>true</default>
      <label-on>Aan</label-on>
      <label-off>Uit</label-off>
 </setting>
```

The type "range", has always the next elements (the values are just an example):

```
 <setting type="range" savename="volumeSettingsGlobFW" color="purple">
         <min>1</min>
         <max>100</max>
         <step>1</step>
         <default>8</default>
         <labelleft>Low</labelleft>
         <labelright>High</labelright>
    </setting>
```

There are 4 types possible.  I added this in the xsd-file, and that works fine:

```
<xs:attribute name="type" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="multibox"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="range"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="select"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="toggle"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
```

But I don't have any idea how I have to implement that the xsd requires for example for range: `

```
<min>
<max>
<step>
<default>
<labelleft>
<labelright>`
```

if you enter:

```
<setting type="range">
```

and requires for example for toggle:

```
<label>
<default>
<label-on>
<label-off>
```

Is it possible to do this anyway with xsd? (P.S. excuse me if my English is bad ;) )

Comment: You can use alternative types in XSD 1.1. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23545674/xml-validation-different-child-tags-based-on-attribute-value

Comment: I don't have an XSD 1.1 procesor, so i can't use alternative types.

Comment: Or maybe it's another problem, but it's a fact that I get an error when I use alternative types.